# get the product automatically from dynamic textbox using javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamic, textbox

I'd been searching for 2 days now and i cant find the solution for my problem.

I wanted to automatically multiplied two numbers from dynamically generated textbox with the use of PHP coming from mysql

FROM THIS

```
<input name="qty<?php echo $x ?>" type="text" id="qty<?php echo $x ?>" size="6" maxlength="10" onfocus="startCalc();" onblur="stopCalc();">
      <td><label>
        <input name="unit<?php echo $x ?>" type="text" id="unit<?php echo $x ?>" size="9" maxlength="12" onfocus="startCalc();" onblur="stopCalc();">
      </label></td>
      <td><input name="total<?php echo $x ?>" type="text" id="total<?php echo $x ?>" size="9" maxlength="12" style="background-color:#FFCC33" readonly></td>
  </tr>
```

heres my javascript

```
function startCalc(){
  interval = setInterval("Unit()",1);

}

function Unit()
{
var cost = document.getElementsByName('unit');
    for(var i=1; i<cost.length; i++)
    {
        unit[i] = document.getElementById('unit' + i).value;
        srr_qty[i]= document.getElementById('qty' + i).value;
        total[i]=(unit[i] * 1)*(qty[i]* 1);
        document.getElementById('srr_total'+ i).value = total[i];
        totalAmount[i]=document.getElementById('total' + i).value;
        return (totalAmount[i])

    }
}

function stopCalc(){
  clearInterval(interval);
}
```

Hope you can understand what i wanted to do.. thanks and hoping for your quick response :)

Answer (score 0):

set the `value` attribute for `input` tags `<input type="text" value="<something here>" />`

Comment: thank you for your reply... But which textbox i needed to write the value.. i can use the code above if it is not multiple textboxes...

Comment: `<input name="unit<?php echo $x ?>" type="text" id="unit<?php echo $x ?>" size="9" maxlength="12" onfocus="startCalc();" onblur="stopCalc();">` in this tag, there is no `value` attribute, but your javascript is trying to retrieve the value from this input field `unit[i] = document.getElementById('unit' + i).value;`. the same applies to the other text field

Comment: oopss.. got confused... i cant think of any words i can replace with " something here" ->value="<something here>" i thought with the use of getElementById i can get the value inputted by the user... sorry am just starting to explore javascript :) thank you again

Comment: try to use any good html and javascript IDEs to edit your code and debuggers file firebug (Firefox plugin) to debug your javascript. you will definitely get a good hold on javascript